# SQL Query from Excel 2007, use in Access 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-access

I have a query written with MS Query in Excel, but I would like to instead run this in Access. I'm getting a "syntax error in query" and not sure what it is.
This is the query:

```
SELECT arcusfil_sql.cus_type_cd,
       artypfil_sql.cus_type_desc,
       oehdrhst_sql.orig_ord_type,
       oehdrhst_sql.ord_type,
       oehdrhst_sql.inv_no,
       oehdrhst_sql.ord_no,
       oehdrhst_sql.bill_to_name,
       oehdrhst_sql.cus_no,
       oelinhst_sql.item_no,
       oelinhst_sql.item_desc_1,
       oehdrhst_sql.inv_dt,
       oelinhst_sql.qty_to_ship,
       imitmidx_sql.commodity_cd,
       imitmidx_sql.prod_cat,
       oelinhst_sql.qty_return_to_stk,
       imcatfil_sql.prod_cat_desc,
       oelinhst_sql.unit_price,
       oelinhst_sql.sls_amt,
       cicmpy.accounttypecode,
       cicmpy.sct_code,
       cicmpy.salespersonnumber
FROM   "001".dbo.arcusfil_sql arcusfil_sql,
       "001".dbo.artypfil_sql artypfil_sql,
       "001".dbo.cicmpy cicmpy,
       "001".dbo.imcatfil_sql imcatfil_sql,
       "001".dbo.imitmidx_sql imitmidx_sql,
       "001".dbo.oehdrhst_sql oehdrhst_sql,
       "001".dbo.oelinhst_sql oelinhst_sql
WHERE  oelinhst_sql.ord_no = oehdrhst_sql.ord_no
       AND oehdrhst_sql.cus_no = arcusfil_sql.cus_no
       AND oehdrhst_sql.ord_type = oelinhst_sql.ord_type
       AND oehdrhst_sql.inv_no = oelinhst_sql.inv_no
       AND artypfil_sql.cus_type_cd = arcusfil_sql.cus_type_cd
       AND imcatfil_sql.prod_cat = oelinhst_sql.prod_cat
       AND imitmidx_sql.item_no = oelinhst_sql.item_no
       AND cicmpy.debcode = oelinhst_sql.cus_no
       AND (( oehdrhst_sql.ord_dt >= {ts '2013-01-01 00:00:00'} ))
```

Comment: Do you have all those tables in Access?

Comment: No, I intended for the query to create the table with the data. This is my first time trying to write a SQL query in Access to query several SQL tables, and I understood that Access would create the tables automatically.

Comment: Well, I don't have much experience with it either, but I think you have to link the database (I'm assuming SQL Server) to MS Access first or import the tables. In your excel, there's probably a data connection which allows the query to be run. Other than that, I don't think I'll be able to help :(